# Laravel pluck with map changes array keys

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with laravel pluck on a map function.Generally I take payments from database like this:

```
$payments = Payment::with('translation')->active()->get();
```

And result is:

[image]

Each payments has different translations so I use function to get proper ones. For that I've added map function to query to get translation like this:

```
$payments = Payment::with('translation')->active()->get()->map(function ($payment) {
            return ['key' => $payment->getName() . ' +' . $payment->cost, 'value' => $payment->id];
        })
->pluck('key', 'value')
->prepend('Choose payment...');
```

And result is:

[image]

Array keys are different from  payment ones. It should be like 1,9,12 etc.

If I switch order of pluck for  value then key result will be with right keys:

[image]

But after that blade forms from htmlcollective ({!! Form::select() !!}) will show keys as dropdown text, and translations as value. (like opposite).

Is there any simple way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It was  prepend causing keys to be wrong. Any prepend without specified key will be automaticaly added as  0 (zero), and all other keys will count from there.

To fix change:

```
->prepend('Any text here');
```

to:

```
->prepend('Any text here', '');
```

Key will be set as '', and other keys will be not changed:

[image]